# How to insert a new row before an existing row in Android sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-insert

My table is not sorted and I keep it sorted in the code logic.

I would like to insert a new row at the beginning of the table - before any other existing row. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: It generally insert the row at the end. but why you are looking to insert at the beginning of the table

Answer (score 2):

SQL tables do not have a defined order; to return rows in a specific order, you *must* use an ORDER BY clause.

In SQLite, table rows are stored in the order of their internal [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) (which is also the value of the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, if any).
To store a row before all other rows, insert the new row with a `rowid` value that is smaller than all others:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(rowid, Name, Comment)
VALUES ((SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM MyTable) - 1, 'me', 'first!');
```

(Please note that the first paragraph still applies; storage order is not guaranteed to be query order. You still need to use ORDER BY.)

Comment: So how do I know what id to put in the rowid that will cause the row to be inserted before others?

Comment: In addition, I read that the rowid starts at 1 and is unsigned, which means that I cannot put rows before it. Source: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html and https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html

Comment: `rowid`s can be negative.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it regularly (like when you want to show latest content first) you can store it normally but reverse the data with query like this.

```
select * from MYTABLE ORDER BY _id DESC
```

this query give you the latest row first.